# Will a PCI Wireless Card Function Without the External Antennae?

Tags: wireless-networking

Without the little black antennae screwed in to the card, will the card pick up wireless signals?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but likely only at the range of a few feet. You should realistically consider the antennae to be necessary to the proper operation of the wireless card.

Comment: Yeah, I have a client who swore up and down that his wireless used to work on his PC but when I looked at the adapter in the back there was no antennae. Very strange - his router was also located atleast a 100 feet away.

Comment: It could at least theoretically have an internal antenna. But if it has a connection for an external which is not currently attached, and if the wifi isn't working, this is certainly the cause.

Comment: I've seen PCI cards with onboard antennas and also external antenna connections -- there the antenna is optional. But I bet it used to work -- back when he had the antenna connected.

Comment: I don't think it ever had one, I interrogated him about the antennae for a solid 10 mins and he didnt seem to remember ever installing one or unscrewing one. I bet it has an onboard antennae but for some reason there just wasn't enough gusto to pickup the signal. I will be getting him an external antennae to see if this alleviates the problem.

Comment: was the computer moved recently?  Sometimes a few feet makes a big difference with WiFi

Comment: @Scandalist -*"an external antennae"* -  "antennae" is plural, i.e. more than one antenna.